# How to get the zombie reaping process worked

Tags: windows-10, docker, vnc, ros

My system is Windows 10 Home and I am running my Docker container in Docker Desktop's  4.23.0  version. When I run my container I am getting this

```
File "/home/catkin_ws/src/CMakeLists.txt" already exists[WARN  tini (73)] Tini is not running as PID 1 and isn't registered as a child subreaper.
Zombie processes will not be re-parented to Tini, so zombie reaping won't work.
To fix the problem, use the -s option or set the environment variable TINI_SUBREAPER to register Tini as a child subreaper, or run Tini as PID 1.
```

warning from container's log. This container supposed to run VNC and GZweb environment on localhost via ports `8081` and `8080` respectively. While I am able to view VNC environment  properly, in GZweb environment the map isn't loading properly, so I believe that somehow zombie process may interfere the loading process of the map. Along with the map the robot model isn't receiving the VNC environment as you can see from the screenshot.

[image: VNC Environment]

I am assuming that this problem is directly related to Linux (never find any solution on Docker Community Discord channels as well as forums). I have done several researches, but I have not found anything. Maybe this community can help me. Also I am attaching my Docker file and entry point script.

**DOCKER FILE**

```
FROM --platform=linux/amd64 crudfab/gazebo_docker:v1

# clone gzweb
RUN cd /home \
    && git clone https://gzweb:glpat-oBrz5yqF84131_DeQmoo@ssyz-git.ssb.gov.tr/kangal-otonomi-yarimasi/gzweb.git

# clone source
RUN mkdir -p /home/catkin_ws/src \
    && cd /home/catkin_ws/src \
    && git clone https://kangal:glpat-URbvXWbozupLiyV8NZvm@ssyz-git.ssb.gov.tr/kangal-otonomi-yarimasi/kangal.git .

COPY ./src /home/catkin_ws/src/examples

RUN cp -r /src/web/dist/* /var/www/html/ \
    && cd /var/www/html/ && chmod -R 777 *


RUN cp -r /src/rootfs/* / \
    && ln -sf /var/www/html/static/websockify var/www/html/static/novnc/utils/websockify && \
    chmod +x /var/www/html/static/websockify/run

WORKDIR /root
ENV HOME=/home/ubuntu \
    SHELL=/bin/bash

COPY ./docker-entrypoint.sh /root/
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash", "/root/docker-entrypoint.sh"]

# setup environment
EXPOSE 8080
EXPOSE 7681
EXPOSE 11311
EXPOSE 9090
EXPOSE 8001
EXPOSE 80
```

**docker-entrypoint.sh file**

```
ln -s /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/python

source /opt/ros/noetic/setup.bash
source /usr/share/gazebo/setup.sh

mkdir -p /home/catkin_ws/src
cd /home/catkin_ws/src/
catkin_init_workspace
cd /home/catkin_ws/
catkin_make
sh /src/rootfs/startup.sh
```

Comment: "To fix the problem, use the -s option or set the environment variable TINI_SUBREAPER to register Tini as a child subreaper, or run Tini as PID 1." it says.